# 'taphold' event disabled after focus on a textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have been using the jQuery UI mobile library and have the following method bound to an element for 'taphold':

```
            // Apply class to annotations details to initiate animation
        $('.detailsDiv').on('taphold', function ()
        {
            var openingID = $(this).parent().attr("annoID");
            var showControls = true;
            if ($(".annoEditableTextArea.annoName").length > 0)

                $('body').append(pThis._getBlackoutOverlay(id));
            }
            else
            {
                $(this).off('mousedown');
                pThis.base.annotations._setAnnotationDetailsActive(openingID, showControls);
            }
        });
```

This hooks the event just fine. However, on iOS safari if I click on a textbox from here after the 'taphold' event does not fire. I've tried to reattach the event after an unfocus of a textbox but still no luck.

Has anyone had any similar experiences with this sort of behavior?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not pin point the exact reason behind this, however I found a similar library from some guys called zauberlabs:

https://github.com/zauberlabs/jquery-tap-and-hold

This was a straight swap, with no extra coding required and solved the problem.

Many thanks,